# How to add items to combobox in Visual Studio 2017RC

Tags: c#, combobox, visual-studio-2017

I tried this and when I press Start it does nothing. I appreciate your support.

```
private void comboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{           
    comboBox.Items.Add(DBNull.Value);
    comboBox.Items.Add("y = x ");
    comboBox.Items.Add("y = x^2 ");
    comboBox.Items.Add("y = x^3 ");
    comboBox.Items.Add("y = |x|");
    comboBox.Items.Add("y = √x ");
    comboBox.Items.Add("y = 1/x ");
}
```

Comment: Do it in the form Load event handler.

Comment: That seems like an odd event to add something to the combo box.  The form's constructor would be more appropriate.

Comment: you should do it the same way that in previous versions. What you are doing is wrong indeed since you are adding items whenever the selection changes, and I´m not sure but that will cause a recursive situation where all the time items are being add